# Center of Self.View

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm trying to center a UIImageView inside the big self.view and using:

```
CGPoint point;
point.x = self.view.center.x;
```

works fine and it's aligned horizontally.
However,

```
self.view.center.y;
```

has a value of 250 for the iPhone simulator, when the image is visually in the center when

self.view.center.y = 230

not 250.

How come the center value for the view is off?

Edit:

I should also mention that I've tried setting the frame but I get the same problem. The center of my image view ends up being 250 not 230 which visually is still off.

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The status bar is 20 points high, if you want your image in the center of *device* screen you  will need to adjust for that. `self.view.center` gives you the center of visible portion of your app's view.

Comment: You, are a god among men. I would have never realized that. Works like a charm.